# CPU-0 constantly in use, even after fresh boot

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

I'm having a problem with my girlfriend's PCs where CPU0 gets a constant 30-50% load. I'm not sure which process is using it but it keeps the CPU on boost clock at all times,  and fans ramped up a bit. This is annoying since I can't even be sure of which process uses this specific thread.

I checked the windows event logs and didn't see any error or warning. Is there a way for me to find which process is responsible of this ? I see that Hardware Interrupts stays fairly high with a constant 2 to 3% usage.

The PC is running Windows 10 with the latest update. Drivers seem up to date and the problem surfaced about 2 weeks ago.

Edit: As harrymc suggested in the comments, it **doesn't** do it in safe mode however. Could it be a driver issue ?

Thank you for your help, you will find below some screenshots to illustrate my problem :

HWMonitor, you can see that CPU0 is at 34% load, preventing the CPU to lower it's clock.

[image: HWMonitor]

Task Manager : You can see that System Interrupts is at 3.7% usage. Which seems odd, on my other PC it never goes over 0.1. Could it be the culprit ? What does System Interrupts mean ?
[image: Task Manager]

Task Manager Performance Tab : This is what I always see, CPU-0 usage stays high but stable, while all the other cores are idling
[image: Task Manager CPU Usage]

Edit 2: Here is a process explorer screenshot (Edit 3: taken as administrator)
[image]

Comment: Does this happen if you boot in Safe Mode?

Comment: I didn't try it, I'll try as soon as I can and report back

Comment: Thank you harrymc, you had a good point : It doesn't do it in safe mode. I'll update my question.

Comment: Task Manager may not be showing all processes. Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to view processes, sorted by "CPU time" in descending order. Please post a screenshot.

Comment: I added a process explorer screenshot in my question after a fresh restart. As you can see, system interrupts is still high on CPU.

Comment: Sorry, still not enough information. Could you repeat it while running Process Explorer as Administrator.

Comment: It almost looks like a driver might be buggy. I say this because 1) the CPU time is being used by "System Interrupts" and 2) the usage is always exactly on the first core - the process scheduler usually will move tasks between cores, so the only way something would explicitly peg a single core is if its affinity were set as such or if it's a system-level process like a driver.

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the screenshot. fdmillion, this was what I thought in the beginning, I ran snappy driver installer and it found some drivers to update but it didn't change anything. Instead now, she can't connect to her bluetooth speakers anymore, the speakers get paired but the connection fails.

Comment: I would think that it's rather a bad device that's generating the interrupts. Try to disconnect or disable everything possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than three years later, and for posterity, I have found the solution!

The front panel audio connector of the case must have been at fault : disconnecting the front panel audio cable from the motherboard fixed the problem. It was a 10 years old case that has now been replaced by a newer one.

I tried to disconnect everything during my tests : GPU, USB devices, secondary hard drives... Everything but the front panel cables...

Good PC cases matter, don't cheap out on it!